# PyDev: Always run the same module

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

This is a simple one.

I'm using PyDev on OS X 10.6. I have a certain module that I run to start my application. Whenever I make changes in other modules I need to switch the view to the starter module to launch or select it from the Run drop down menu. I'm curious, is there a shortcut or setting to set the default module to run whenever you press Run/launch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Preferences > Run / Debug > Launching**

Under "Launch Operation", select "Always launch the previously launched application"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can press the Restart the current launch icon in the console